# How can I make mobs stronger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a zombie boss, and I'm giving it a sword, but this is deemed useless since it won't use the sword. So is there any way I can make its natural attack damage bigger? To be honest, I just started doing commands a while ago so I'm no professional at this, but I have got the zombie's armour done. And I'm not talking about strength potions, because I need the zombie to do about 5 hearts of damage to players (excluding armour).

Comment: I dont see why this question is getting downvoted. Its a good question and hasn't been asked before, its not opinion based and not offencive in any way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using a command block with a [summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon) command. Basically. you need to specify the data tag on the command to give the mob the desired attributes. For attack damage, that would look something like this:

```
summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.attackDamage­,Base:10}]}
```

Here `attackDamage` is measured in half hearts, so this command would span a giant zombie which does 5 hearts of damage per hit.

See also: [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute) with some more information about attributes.

To get a command block, type:

```
/give <username> minecraft:command_block
```

Comment: @123man Does this answer meet your needs? If so, please accept.